# How to reset Alpine distro in WSL2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I completely *borked* my Alpine configuration when attempting to connect Docker Desktop several times. I've done the usual *--unregister Alpline* and then reinstalling from the app store.

Is there a quicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work in Windows 11 Pro without touching the UI.

1. Open *Windows Powershell* in *Windows Terminal*.
2. Verify that Alpine is installed: *wsl -l -v*
3. Unregister Alpine: *wsl --unregister Alpine*
4. Verify that Alpine has been unregistered: *wsl -l -v*
5. Register Alpine by starting it: *Alpine*

Unregistering the Alpine distro from WSL does not delete it from your system.